# Отправка файла ajax + поля

Tags: ajax, javascript

Есть страница с которой отправляется успешно поля post запросом. Все данные идут как то так:

```
data: "name="  + $('#name').val()
```

Как вместе с этим отправить еще и файл?

Answer (score 1):

Нет кроссбраузерного решения отправки файла через XHR. Есть костыли, но в итоге, ни чего хорошего не получится. Для отправки файлов без перезагрузки страницы, лучше использовать iframe, погуглите. Так же, могу посоветовать JQuery плагин, хорошо справляющийся с задачей отправки форм: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/